# checking for validity of a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string, in which I want to make sure that every '_' is followed by a capital letter.
(and I need to do it on one regex)
How can I do it?
_[A-Z] is good if it finds only one, but will still match if I have: foo_Bar_bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the other way around with something like:

```
/_[^A-Z]/
```

This will match if the string contains `_` followed by anything but a capital letter. If it matches, then the string is malformed according to your criteria.

Sample in perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/_[^A-Z]/) { print "** bad\n" } else { print "** good\n"; };'
qsdkjhf
** good          # no _ at all
qdf_A
** good          # capital after _
qdsf_2
** bad           # no capital after _
qsdf__Aqs  
** bad           # the first _ is followed by another _ => not a capital
_
** bad           # end of input after _ is also rejected
```

Comment: he still needs a positive assertion check in addition to the negative case.  Allowing "not failure" isn't sufficient for success.

Comment: @Mike: I'm not sure I understand your point. would you have an example of what this would not work on?

Comment: your regex still passes "_2", which is not a capital letter

Comment: @Mike: "_2" matches that RE, which means the string is "malformed". "_A" doesn't match, which means it's "ok".

Comment: thanks @mat.
@Mike: I am not interested in the instances themselves, so I have no need in the positive results. but thanks for the second comment because I realized that a number is also legal :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
(([_][A-Z])|[^_])+
```

It will match any character that is not "_" and when it encounters an underscore it will match only if is followed by a capital letter.